# Get connected apple watch details in swift

Tags: swift, wcsession

in my xcode when i am opening "simulator and devices", there i can see my iphone and connected apple watch name. i want to get the apple watch name so that i can show the device to user in my app. how to get the connected apple watch details and the connection status. can any one help me to do this.And when i am trying code to get status of pairing every time it is showing no paired device even if it is paired.

```
 wcSession = WCSession.default
              wcSession.delegate = self
              wcSession.activate()
        if wcSession.isPaired { // Check if the iPhone is paired with the Apple Watch
                   // Do stuff
           }
```

[image]